# Saving User Settings in Univeral App for Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I am a self-taught programmer, so please be gently. Please give as much feedback as possible for my code.

I want to make sure I am doing things the right way and efficient way.

What is the proper directory to save this info? What file type and what format?

How do I load these settings when the program loads and make sure I update the UI properly? I currently do this, but have to call Cache.init() in my main views initializer, then once the View that has the listView I use get's initialized I then ReadVideoFolderSettings beause I passed the View's object to the cache.

My program will let the user select folders that contain movies, and I will check to see if the directory/path is already in the settings, if not I will add it to the settings.

The CreateFolders method of the Cache seems excessive, and I think there is a better way to save this info instead of a .dat file. Thoughts? It is really hard to find Windows 10 examples.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace Movie_Management_Windows_10.Business
{
    using Views;
    public static class Cache
    {
        private static StorageFile SettingsFile;
        private static StorageFolder VideosFolder;
        private static List<String> LocatedFolders = new List<String>();
        private static AddVideoFolder VideoView;

        public static void Init()
        {
            CreateFolders();            
        }

        public static void LoadVideoView(AddVideoFolder videoView)
        {
            VideoView = videoView;
            ReadVideoFolderSettings();
        }

        private static async void CreateFolders()
        {
            StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            VideosFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("\\Videos\\", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);            
            StorageFolder settingsFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Settings\\", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            SettingsFile = await settingsFolder.CreateFileAsync("settings.dat", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);           
        }

        private static async void ReadVideoFolderSettings()
        {
            try
            {
                if (SettingsFile != null)
                {
                    string fileContent = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(SettingsFile);
                    string[] rows = fileContent.Split('\n');
                    foreach(string row in rows)
                    {
                        string trimmedRow = row.Trim();
                        LocatedFolders.Add(trimmedRow);
                        VideoView.AddToListView(trimmedRow);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                //how?
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
        }

        private static bool VideoExists(string path)
        {
            foreach(string row in LocatedFolders)
            {
                if (row == path)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static async void AddVideoFolderToSettings(string path)
        {
            if (!VideoExists(path))
            {
                string settingsData = "";
                foreach(string row in LocatedFolders)
                {
                    settingsData += row;
                }
                settingsData += path + "\r\n";
                LocatedFolders.Add(path + "\r\n");
                await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(SettingsFile, settingsData);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The Init method is called from my Main App after the this.InitializeComponent();

```
public AppShell()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Cache.Init();
            this.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Current = this;

                this.TogglePaneButton.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
            };

            this.RootSplitView.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(
                SplitView.DisplayModeProperty,
                (s, a) =>
                {
                    // Ensure that we update the reported size of the TogglePaneButton when the SplitView's
                    // DisplayMode changes.
                    this.CheckTogglePaneButtonSizeChanged();
                });

            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += SystemNavigationManager_BackRequested;

            NavMenuList.ItemsSource = navlist;
        }
```

There is a listView that I want to add the directories to. I do this from the AddVideoFolder view of my application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.AccessCache;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace Movie_Management_Windows_10.Views
{
    using Business;
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class AddVideoFolder : Page
    {
        public AddVideoFolder()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Cache.LoadVideoView(this);
        }

        private void buttonAddVideoFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddBrowsedFolder();
        }

        private async void AddBrowsedFolder()
        {
            FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
            folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".avi");
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".flv");


            StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            if(folder != null)
            {
                StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
                Cache.AddVideoFolderToSettings(folder.Path);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        public void AddToListView(string Path)
        {            
            this.listViewAddedVideoFolders.Items.Add(Path);
        }
    }
}
```

The way I add to the user interface is I pass the AddVideoFolder object instance to the Cache's LoadVideoView method. How else am I supposed to update the UI?

Comment: Instead of the `Init()` method you should have a static constructor like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721832/c-sharp-static-class-constructor

Comment: Thanks Heslacher, I have modified some of my other code and tried to make sure each function / method only has one job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Namespaces

Maybe it's just nitpicking, but it should be pointed out nonetheless:

> ```
> namespace Movie_Management_Windows_10.Business
> ```

Namespace names should respect the same naming convention as types, and be `PascalCase`. `Capital_Snake_Case` just doesn't look right. If your app can be compiled/targeted for platforms other than Win10, and stuff in that namespace is Win10-specific, then consider this:

```
namespace MovieManagement.Win10.Business
```

Otherwise, "universal app" doesn't strike me as something that should be coded with a specific OS in mind, so this would be more like it:

```
namespace MovieManagement.Business
```

I don't like the term `Business` though: it doesn't convey anything at all and tells me that if I expand that folder, I'll find just about *anything* in there.

I'd much rather see this:

```
namespace MovieManagement.Storage
```

Now *that* tells me something. I expand that folder and expect to find everything there is to know about how the application deals with the concern of *storage*.

---

#### #using Namespace

Okay another nitpick - your `using` statements should be grouped together; this is rather unusual:

```
using Views;
public static class Cache
```

---

#### Rethrowing Exceptions

This is very unfortunate:

> ```
> catch (FileNotFoundException)
> {
>     //how?
>     throw new FileNotFoundException();
> }
> ```

You're catching an exception that contains valuable information about what happened, but then you discard/swallow it and throw a new exception instead - the outcome is the same, the client code sees a `FileNotFoundException`. But the stack trace is lost, along with all the information that the original exception had. If you don't want to handle an exception, *let it go* - let it *bubble up* to the caller.

If you otherwise want to handle it, but *still* rethrow the exception to the caller, you should do it like this:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
{
    // e.g. Debug.WriteLine(exception);
    throw;
}
```

---

#### Async Event Handling.

The `AddBrowsedFolder` method is going to run synchronously:

> ```
> private void buttonAddVideoFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
> {
>     AddBrowsedFolder();
> }
>
> private async void AddBrowsedFolder()
> {
>     ...
> }
> ```

Also, `AddBrowsedFolder` doesn't respect the naming convention for `async` methods. This would be right:

```
private async void buttonAddVideoFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await AddBrowsedFolderAsync();
}

private async Task AddBrowsedFolderAsync()
{
    ...
}
```

The only time `async void` is acceptable, is for calling `async` code from an event handler. Otherwise, a "void" async method should return a `Task`; the reason you can't make an event handler return a `Task` is because the `EventHandler<T>` delegate specifies a `void` return type.

---

#### Redundant Code

Get rid of code that doesn't need to exist:

> ```
>         else
>         {
>
>         }
> ```

An empty `else` scope is just clutter. Kill with fire.

---

#### FileTypes

You've hard-coded the supported file extensions:

> ```
>         folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
>         folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".avi");
>         folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".flv");
> ```

This would be more flexible:

```
private readonly IEnumerable<string> _fileExtensions;

public AddVideoFolder(IEnumerable<string> fileExtensions)
{
    _fileExtensions = fileExtensions;

    this.InitializeComponent();
    Cache.LoadVideoView(this);
}
```

and then you can do this:

```
 foreach(var extension in _fileExtensions)
 {
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(extension);
 }
```

and not have to change anything in this class when you need to support format `.xyz`.

The name `AddVideoFolder` is a bad name for a class. Keep verbs for methods, use nouns for types. Yes, naming is hard. But it's worth it.